Identify component marked "f AA51 LM"
I’m trying to repair a faulty OTDR device. I found that the "f AA51 LM" SMD component was shorted, so I replaced it with what I guessed was a Zener diode. However, after making this replacement, the device started behaving oddly. Could someone help me identify the correct SMD component?

Figure 1. Unknown component

Figure 2. Photo of PCB where unknown component was located

Simmon Rilley - Hi, I've refocused the question on the part which is on-topic here i.e. where you ask for help identifying that component and away from your project to repair the OTDR. If you ask repair questions here, there are additional requirements (e.g. for you to provide more information, like schematics). So I've tried to help by focusing on what you can ask here, while leaving the overall repair project to you. || It doesn't identify the specific component but FYI the "f" in "f AA51 LM" marking is the old Fairchild Semiconductor logo. Hopefully another site member can help...

Finding Fairchild component marking style
A comment on the question already notes the leading "f" in the marking is the old Fairchild Semiconductor logo.
This distributor web page onsemi / Fairchild S1D has the following picture, which looks similar to the marking style of the component in the question:

Fairchild is now part of onsemi. The S1M_D datasheet shows the marking style as:

So:

The first line of the marking is the manufacturer logo, assembly plant code, and year / weekly code of manufacturer
The second line is the specific device code

Identifying the component marked "f AA51 LM"
For the device in the question LM would be the device code.
The onemi / fairchild SMBJ15CA datasheet shows the part marking LM is for a "ESD Protection Diodes / TVS Diodes 15V 600W SMB Bidirectional"
